# Socket Client/Server using multiple ports

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, tcplistener

At first I'm new in network programming.
Assume we have server application which is listening port 5001, so when client app establish a  connection with server is it possible to open a dedicated port for that client and use that port and keep 5001 only for accepting client connection requests?

Comment: Why? You don't need another connection or another port. TCP works just fine the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just keep accepting new sockets with the listener socket. No need to do anything special.

Comment: -1. The accepted socket uses the *same* local port as the listening socket, and you can verify *that* by printing out the local port of the accepted socket, or with 'netstat'.

Comment: Correct. My mistake. Mixed it up with the connecting client which gets a random local port per default.

Comment: but what if i want to assign a dedicated port to each client ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Each accepted socket can only communicate with the client that connected.

Comment: --1, but it's a strange thing to get mixed up about: the OP's question is clear, if pointless.

Comment: @OP You have now been asked three separate times why you want something you don't need. Until you answer that you are just wasting time.

Comment: suppose we have 20K clients how can one port accept so many requests without any lags? that's why i want a dedicated port for each client or group of clients

Comment: @taffarel There are no lags, and no requirement for multiple ports, or client groups. There is no problem here to solve. Every server on the Internet works this way. There is no reason for yours to be any different.